# Use lookbehind to ignore a string between two matches, but capture it anyway

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to match instances of '**the** *blah blah* **noun**' throughout a text, where the *blah blah* can include many words, but NOT 'the'.

This regex:

```
/(\b([Tt]he|[Aa]n|[Aa]|[Aa]nother)\b)?((?!\b(the|an?|another)\b).)*\b(cat|apple)\b/g
```

Produces these matches:
**The small cat** sat on **a huge black cat** and ate **an apple**.

I tried some regex here: https://regexr.com/674l6

The matching is working, but I can't capture complete matches. When you hover over the matches in regexr, not all capture groups are available. I'm only able to capture the beginning and end of the matched string.

There's a basic demo [here](https://www.ialf.edu/onlineification/show_articles.php).

I've been tweaking the regex for hours but to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the characters in the middle, you only have a match for the last single char in a capture group, as you are repeating the capture group.

You can add a capture group around the whole that you are matching, and turn the repeating capture group in a non capture group.

As you want to match **the** *blah blah* **noun** the first capture group should not be optional.

The match now has 3 capture groups instead of 5.

```
\b([Tt]he|[Aa]n(?:other)?|[Aa])\b((?:(?!\b(?:the|an?|another)\b).)*)\b(cat|apple)\b
```

The updated pattern in parts:

- `\b` A word boundary to prevent a partial match
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `[Tt]he|[Aa]n(?:other)?|[Aa]` Match one of the alternatives
- `)` Close group 1
- `\b` A word boundary
- `(` Capture **group 2**

  - `(?:(?!\b(?:the|an?|another)\b).)*` Repeat matching any char not directly followed by any of the alternatives (tempered greedy token)
- `)` Close group 2
- `\b(cat|apple)\b` Capture **group 3**, match either cat or apple between word boundaries

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/YKu4LM/1)

See a [non greedy pattern version](https://regex101.com/r/rMex9u/1) to not capture the surrounding spaces in group 2.

Comment: Thank you so much. Sometimes there is no 'a' or 'the' with a noun. If the text is "Cats are adorable." and I want to highlight the noun 'Cats', can the regex be tweaked to allow for this? - \b([Tt]he|[Aa]n(?:other)?|[Aa])\b((?:(?!\b(?:the|an?|another)\b).)*)\b(Cats)\b

Comment: @SteveBolton Like this? https://regex101.com/r/lJCXlE/1

Comment: @SteveBolton Did it work out?

Comment: For the nouns that have articles (the/a/an, etc), yes that works nicely. I still need a way to deal with nouns that do not have articles - in this example the word 'sources': https://regex101.com/r/MIM83i/1. Probably easier to handle those using a separate expression.